# Time difference in dataframe columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dt

Following the [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35700972/finding-time-difference-between-two-columns-in-dataframe) and [and here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48647089/trying-to-get-the-time-delta-between-two-date-columns-in-a-dataframe-where-one). I first change the dataframe to a time object

```
data['start'] = pd.to_datetime(data_session['start'], format = '%H:%M:%S').dt.time

data['end'] = pd.to_datetime(data['end'], format = '%H:%M:%S').dt.time
data['minutes'] = (data['end'] - data['start']).dt.minutes
data['Hour'] = data['start'].dt.hour
```

I get this error:

```
Error:TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.time' and 'datetime.time'
```

I checked what the data frame info as:

```
data.info()
    start    10000 non-null object
    end      10000 non-null object
```

The column is still an object type. Why doesn't it convert to datetime64? Why am I not able to access it using the [dt](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html#datetimelike-properties) accessor?

My last try was:

```
data['start'] = pd.to_datetime(data_session['start'], format = '%H:%M:%S')
data['end'] = pd.to_datetime(data['end'], format = '%H:%M:%S')
data['minutes'] = (data['end'] - data['start'])

data.info()
    start    10000 non-null datetime64[ns]
    end      10000 non-null datetime64[ns]
```

This solution **worked partially** as I got the time difference but my start and end column had an additional date included.

```
e.g: 06:10:10 -> 1900-01-01 06:10:10
```

My goals are:

- Make a new column with only the hour of one of the series
- Make a new column with time difference in minutes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think need convert [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_timedelta.html)s and then convert to minutes and hours:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'end':['12:01:04','15:21:00'],
                     'start':['10:01:04','5:41:00']})

data['start'] = pd.to_timedelta(data['start'])
data['end'] = pd.to_timedelta(data['end'])

data['minutes'] = (data['end'] - data['start']).dt.total_seconds() / 60
data['Hour'] = data['start'].astype('timedelta64[h]').astype(int)
print (data)
       end    start  minutes  Hour
0 12:01:04 10:01:04      120    10
1 15:21:00 05:41:00      580     5
```

Comment: but the minutes are not calculate correct when the time is switching. For example: 23:59:44 to 00:01:41 the minutes are -1439, which is wrong

Comment: @may - You are right. Minutes was wrong, but answer was changed. Please check it.

Comment: Thanks! I prefer your answer because is easier to follow. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

This is one way using `operator.attrgetter`. Data from @jezrael.

```
from operator import attrgetter

for col in ['start', 'end']:
    data[col] = pd.to_timedelta(data[col])

data['minutes'] = (data['end'] - data['start']).apply(attrgetter('seconds')) / 60
data['hour'] = (data['start'].apply(attrgetter('seconds')) / 60**2).astype(int)

print(data)

       end    start  minutes  hour
0 12:01:04 10:01:04    120.0    10
1 15:21:00 05:41:00    580.0     5
```

Comment: this answer seems to work to calculate the minutes correctly, thanks